# Apache server file permissions for python program

Tags: python, apache, file, permissions

I have a strange problem with my site. To begin with i have a site that collects some data, then stores them in a MySQL database and then a Python program is called. While everything runs fine the Python program does not work as supposed to because of file permissions.
The problem starts when the python code creates some folders and puts some files in them. While the files are created nothing gets written in them. When I look for the permissions of the files it seems that they are created by "www-data" user. Why the Python program has no permissions for the files it creates?

P.S. I should point out that everything works when I run it from terminal as a regular user, or my localhost configuration!

Comment: To which directory are it attempting to write the files? Are you using Windows or Linux? If you're using Linux, what does `ls -ld <output-directory>` say?

Comment: I'm using linux. Unfortunately I don't have access to the server right now to try the command. But it is a folder for a user because the path has "~" and the "official" folder is under /var/www. So the files are in a path that looks like "home/.../~user/PYTHON_PROGRAM".